# How to display a difference modal popup According to click button

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

Hello friends  i have 4 modal popup, and i want to display one by one according to click buttons. this buttons is in foreach
this is my foreach

```
  <div class="col-sm-6 poleA">
      @foreach($competences as $competence)
        <?php $var = $var+1; ?>
     <div class="developemnt">
     <div class="poleaa"><img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$competence->image) }}" class="img-responsive icone" alt="Placeholder image">
      <h1 class="titrepole"> {{ $competence->titre }} </h1>
      <p class="parapole">
        {{ $competence->description }}
       </p>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btnpole" data-
       toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Demander Votre Devis</button>
      </div>
      </div>
        @if($var == 2)
        @break;
        @endif
      @endforeach
        <?php $var = 0; ?>
    </div>
```

When i click a button i want to display a modal according the event select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to customise your `data-target` to reference a unique modal that corresponds to your `$var` / iteration:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btnpole" data-
   toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal{{$var}}">Demander Votre Devis</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btnpole" data-
   toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal{{$var}}">Demander Votre Devis</button>
```

If you have modals with that ID in your code, they'll be triggered :)

Comment: Perfect! Don't forget to mark it as the answer :-) Happy coding!